# How to get an array of 2-tuples from Laravel query builder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Basically, I want to do this:

```
$locals['companies'] = Company::orderBy('name')->get(['id','name'])->map(function($c) { return [$c->id, $c->name]; })->toArray();
```

But without such a verbose `map` function. Isn't there a get-like method that will return flat numeric arrays instead of objects?

To be clear, the output should look like this:

```
array:4 [
  0 => array:2 [
    0 => 4
    1 => "My Company"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    0 => 14
    1 => "Example Company"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    0 => 13
    1 => "Best Company"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [
    0 => 12
    1 => "Super Co"
  ]
]
```

This is what I mean by 2-tuples: two-element numeric arrays. I know they don't exist in PHP, but the concept is the same; each entry has a fixed length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function out of the box to do this, but Laravel's `Collection` is `Macroable`, so you can add your own function to it to do this.

For example, somewhere in your code (like the `boot()` method of your `AppServiceProvider`), you can add a new method to the `Collection`:

```
// add toIndexedArray method to collections
\Illuminate\Support\Collection::macro('toIndexedArray', function() {
    return array_map('array_values', $this->toArray());
});
```

Now you can use this new method like any other normal `Collection` method, so your final code would be:

```
$locals['companies'] = Company::orderBy('name')->get(['id','name'])->toIndexedArray();
```

Comment: Oh, neat! I didn't know you could extend `Collection`s.

Answer (score 1):

If this is something you need a lot, you can change the PDO fetch mode in config/database.php to `PDO::FETCH_NUM`. I'm assuming it's possible to change it on-the-fly as well, but the code probably won't look that great. I don't think there's a Laravel command to change it for a single query, I'm afraid.

Otherwise, since the array is multidimensional, I'm afraid you do need to map over them somehow, and Laravel collections don't work nicely with e.g. `->map('array_values')` which would have been a lot cleaner.

You could wrap it in `array_map('array_values', $array)` but that seems silly.

At least you could make it a little shorter if you change `->map()` to `->transform()` - then you don't need to tack on the `->toArray()` at the end.

Comment: All my drop-downs use this format so I'll need it quite a bit. I guess I'll use transform with a custom function then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck):

```
$locals['companies'] = Company::orderBy('name')->pluck('id', 'name')->toArray();
```

If you need a list for `Form::select` this will work:

```
$locals['companies'] = Company::orderBy('name')->pluck('name', 'id');
```

Comment: Right from the docs, that returns: `['prod-100' => 'Desk', 'prod-200' => 'Chair']`. I want *numeric* indices. i.e., the answer should be `[['prod-100','Desk'],['prod-200','Chair']]`.

Comment: I guess `map()` is the best solution then.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the map function and just do:

```
$locals['companies'] = Company::orderBy('name')->get(['id','name'])->toArray();
```